# Minimum value of $(\sin x + \cos x)^3 + \frac{1}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}$

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

Let $\sin x + \cos x = t\qquad (\vert t \vert \leq \sqrt2)$

and solve it as $t^3 + \dfrac{4}{(t^2 - 1)^2}$

Is there any easier solution to solve this $(\sin x + \cos x)^3 + \dfrac{1}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}$?

Is there any available inequality can solve it?

Please help!

Comment: For what it's worth, I would not consider solving it any other way than $$t^3 + \dfrac{4}{(t^2 - 1)^2}.$$ As a practical matter, in my opinion, below the post-graduate level, if you are sure of an (inelegant) approach, that's what you should stick with.  That is, if an elegant approach doesn't occur to you in 15 minutes, an approach that you are **completely** sure about (and therefore it is not an idea that is somewhat new to you), then I advise trudging forward inelegantly.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be a specific inequality, but sure there is a faster way.

$$(\sin x + \cos x)^3 + \dfrac{1}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}=2\sqrt{2}\left(\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)^{3}+4\csc^{2}\left(2x\right)$$

Observe that only the expression having an odd power can contribute to reducing the value of the expression. That is, when $\sin(x+\pi/4)$ is the lowest.

A possible solution is $x=-\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ which gives the global minimum as $4-2\sqrt{2}=1.1715728\dots$

Here is a graphical solution in aid of the above.

[image: graph]